# Adjusting Tables

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to create a macro using VB that will convert many rows of data into a table. I want to store this macro and run it again and again. The one issue is that each time I will run it, there will be a different amount of rows.

The code I am using now is:

```
'CREATE NEW TABLE
Sub CreateTable2()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$922"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "MyNewTable2"
        'No go in 2003
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyNewTable2").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
End Sub
```

The above code will only go as far as '922' rows. I am looking for a way that can adjust to the amount of rows each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is construct the range using Range.End().

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
 Range("$A$1:$H$" & Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row), , xlYes).Name = "MyNewTable2"
```